# Divisibility Test using Last digit truncation Algorithm of larger blocks of final digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility, diophantine-equations

I'm currently carrying on a project based on [the article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07468342.2021.1845530/) by Frey and Hammet in 2021 College Maths Journal.

This article is written about how to generate divisibility tests from truncating the very final digit of a dividend, and there is a section regarding truncation of larger blocks of final digits which the authors did not give in the paper.

Let $\beta \geq 1$ be the amount of final digits which are going to be truncated using the "Last digit truncation method."

For any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ which $\gcd(m,10) = 1$,
$$mx = 10y \pm c \iff x = \pm j + 10t, y = \pm k + mt, t \in \mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$m \mid n \iff m \mid \frac{n - a_0}{10} \mp ya_0$$
where $mx = 10y \pm 1$ and $a_0$ is the last digit of $n$.

This is the algorithm in the case of $\beta = 1$.

Now, I have supposed the claim (Induction hypothesis):
$$mx = 10^{\kappa}y \pm c \iff x = \pm j + 10^{\kappa}t, y = \pm k + mt, t \in \mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$m \mid n \iff m \mid \frac{n - \sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i}{10^{\kappa}} \mp y\sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i $$
where $mx = 10^{\kappa}y \pm 1$ and $a_i$ is the last $i$ digits of $n$, is true for all $\beta = \kappa \geq 1$

It's easy to see that the first equivalence is true for $\kappa + 1$, or analogously, for all $\beta \geq 1$.

The problem is at the second equivalence.

Consider $n = a_{s}10^s + a_{s-1}10^{s-1} + ... + a_{1}10 + a_0$.
From the claim, we know that
$$m \mid n \iff m \mid \frac{n - \sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i}{10^{\kappa}} \mp y\sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i$$
We can then suppose that
$\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    n' & = \frac{n - \sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i}{10^{\kappa}} \mp y\sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i\\
    & = a_{s}10^{s-\kappa} + a_{s-1}10^{s-\kappa-1} + ... + a_{\kappa+1}10 + a_{\kappa}\\
    & \hspace{0.5cm} \mp y(a_{\kappa-1}10^{\kappa-1} + a_{\kappa-2}10^{\kappa-2} + ... +a_{1}10 + a_0)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$

which implies
$$m \mid n \iff m \mid n'$$
Without loss of generality,
$\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    m \mid n' & \iff m \mid \frac{n'-a_{\kappa}}{10} \mp ya_{\kappa}\\
    & \iff m \mid \frac{n'-a_{\kappa}}{10} \mp ya_{\kappa}\\
    & \iff m \mid \frac{(\frac{n - \sum^{\kappa-1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i}{10^{\kappa}}\mp y\sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i) - a_{\kappa}}{10}\mp ya_{\kappa}\\
 & \iff m \mid \frac{n - \sum^{\kappa-1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i \mp 10^{\kappa}y\sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i - 10^{\kappa} a_{\kappa}}{10^{\kappa+1}}\mp ya_{\kappa}\\
& \iff m \mid \frac{n - \sum^{\kappa-1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i \mp 10^{\kappa}y\sum^{\kappa - 1}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i - 10^{\kappa} a_{\kappa} \mp 10^{\kappa + 1}ya_{\kappa}}{10^{\kappa+1}}\\
& \iff m \mid \frac{n - \sum^{\kappa}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i}{10^{\kappa+1}} \mp y\sum^{\kappa}_{i=0} 10^{i}a_i\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}$

Does my progress look strange? I feel like I have mistaken in the proof. Can somebody spot it for me? Send help!